# IoT devices recommendations

Tags: sms, iot

I'm really new to IoT and its devices and need some recommendations about different devices. I need devices that be able to work with telephone network(e.g. SIM card) as well as working with internet.for example, can get commands from a service like SMS and apply it to the environment like house or can send information about house to the owner by SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several IoT hardware like Raspberry Pi, Arduino and others depending on your requirements. You can use GSM shied extension for some hardware (e.g. Arduino GSM Shield) or external like modem dongle via USB Port for others.

Then, you can use C/C++, Java, Python, ... to do actions when receiving an SMS message.

Links that may help:

[Sending SMS messages with Java](https://github.com/tdelenikas/smslib-v3/blob/master/src/java/examples/modem/SendMessage.java)

[Sending and receiving SMS messages with Java](http://gsmmodemtutoialbysamyan.blogspot.com/)

[Sending and receiving SMS messages with C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ranjancse/send-receive-and-delete-sms-with-iot-devices-arduino-and-g/)

Comment: Thank you very much, Arduino boards helped me and now I'm using them.